# How can I remove a node group from my startup file?

Tags: node-editor

I wanted to import some node groups into a new project to save as my startup file so that I will always have them. I accidentally imported one of the nodes I wanted, as well as a junk copy that I had created. I've tried everything I can think of to delete it, and haven't found anything helpful online. The node was originally a copy of the Rectangular to Polar node group, but is now empty and has been renamed Untitled. I suppose I could simply use it next time I need a new node group, but I'd rather just get rid of it. Is there any way to do this?[image: Node Groups Dropdown][image: Node Group]

Comment: If you have already saved that group into startup file then you should be able to make that group orphan. Delete the material where the group is added, save the startup file (because you've saved it with group) and reload. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45992/1245 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7826/1245

Comment: I don't think the node is being used anywhere, but I can't get it to be "orphaned." My understanding is that the "F" should be an "Ö" when it's orphaned.

Comment: If you mean that 0 number should appear next to the group name then no, it won't show number of users in that way. The group will become orphan as long as no materials use it; so if you have one material using it, Shift click on X button to drop it entirely. The group will become orphan and will be deleted (after reload). In you case it's necessary also to save startup file after deleting material and before reload.

Answer (score 7):

Steps:

- Open up a new Blender file (aka. the startup file)
- In the Outliner, select "Data-Blocks" from the drop-down menu
- Find the "Node Groups" section, which should contain the node groups that you are trying to remove
- Expand one of the node groups and uncheck the "Fake User" field
- Repeat this for all the node groups that you want to remove
- Save the file as the start up file, close and open a new Blender file

The node groups that do not have any users will not be saved and thus will not be there when the startup file is loaded. If you have multiple node groups to remove and they have dependencies upon each other, then it may be necessary to save the startup file, close, open new, and save again a couple of times. Each time, the node groups without any dependencies (leaves) will be pruned and eventually you can remove all unwanted node groups.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently delete your nodes, collections, meshes, and materials in your blend file, follow these steps:

- Open your Blend file
- In **Outliner** hover to **Display Mode**
- Select **Blender File**
- **Right click** and select **Delete**

[image]