# append shader⊶node group from another blender file - in update style

Tags: shaders, append, shader-nodes

I created a lot of node group in file `template.blend` as template.
Then, I created `C1.blend`, `C2.blend`, etc, using node group from `template`.

To use the node group in `template`, I simply copied & paste an object that has material reference to the node groups.

It worked very well.

[image]

Today, I find that some of the node group are wrong, so I update them in `template`.

Below is an example that my node group was wrong.  It is sometimes also related to node missing (e.g. must add 1 before the next operation).
[image]

How to update all copied node groups of `C1.blend` to match the change in `template`?

**Similar question :**
[How to remove duplicated node groups?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45992/how-to-remove-duplicated-node-groups) , but this old one aimed to use the oldest version, not the most updated one.

Comment: What *exactly* is *wrong*? Please provide more details about the group itself and ideally a before/after comparison. In general: once the groups are *appended* there is no direct link back to the node group in your template file so what would have to do is replacing the data-block of the old one by the new one which can be done manually or using python.

Comment: @brockmann :: Thanks. I add an example of 'wrong'. I will try to use python. ^^

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK There is no direct link back to the node group in your template file once the group is *appended* so what you would have to do is *appending the new group* and replace the *data-block* of the old one:

[image]

You might want to use python to automate this process for all materials within the blend file:

```
import bpy

D = bpy.data

for mat in D.materials:
    if hasattr(mat.node_tree, "nodes"):
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'GROUP':
                if node.node_tree.name == "Template v1":
                    node.node_tree = D.node_groups['Template v2']
```